# Eigenspace of certain block hermitian matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Suppose I have a special block, Hermitian matrix $F(t):= 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   H & t \bar S \\
   tS & \bar H \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ where '-' denotes  complex conjugate. The blocks H and S are themselves Hermitian and Complex Symmetric respectively in this case and $t \in \mathbb R .$ $E_k(H)$ stands for the eigenspace belonging to $\lambda_k(H)$. Here we consider the eigenvalues in decreasing order. For a unit vector $v$ in $\mathbb C^n$.
$$\mathcal{U_v:= {\
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1v  \\
   \bar z_{2}\bar v\\
  \end{array} } \right]}; z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C}
$$
Let $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_d$ be a basis of the the eigenspace $E_k(H)$.

I am unable to prove that $E_{2k-1}(F(0))=E_{2k}(F(0))= \bigoplus \limits_{j=1}^d \mathcal U_{v_{j}} .$ Where $\bigoplus$ denotes the direct sum.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: What does the subscript $k$ mean? Is $\lambda_k$ the $k$'th largest eigenvalue? Also obviously two different eigenspaces can not be the same space, unless your counting of eigenvalues allows $\lambda_{2k-1} = \lambda_{2k}$. Do you perhaps mean that the the two spaces have equal dimension?

Comment: Here we consider the eigenvalues in decreasing order.